# AWS lambda timeourt exception

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, async-await, aws-lambda

We have a .Net Core lambda function and under that, we have one asynchronous for loop which is calling a stored procedure for each of the loop items. It is working fine but sometimes throws an exception

> The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed

And we are getting this exception in AWS cloud watch logs. Please suggest what could be the cause here.

```
 locations.ForEach(async location =>
                        {
                                await _dataServiceWrite.SaveDeletedLocationDelegateAssignment(location.LocationId, obj.DelegateId, hsId, userId);
                                await Task.Delay(100);
                        });
```

Comment: Increase the timeout and give it some more tries. Is it Sql's timeout? Running this in AWS lambda? or it is just c# lambda expression?

Comment: `.ForEach` looks like a bad way to do anything async to start with

Comment: This snippet is in .Net Core AWS lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

AWS lambda has a limit of 15 minutes max time, after which it will timeout. This is a configurable setting in Lambda and please see whether it can be increased to max to fit your requirement. Still, the architecture might not scale when more records need to be processed.

Comment: We have already set 15 mins max time for AWS lambda function.

Comment: Please revisit the architecture for this process. 

One solution can be 


Use an SQS to push all the requests and use SQS Listener (AWS Lambda) to pull the request and process it. Once the process is complete, another SQS can be used to push the status of the update for all the processed requests. A UI listener, with SQS SDK can listen to this new queue and render the UI accordingly.

Comment: Actually sorry to not mention, we have the same flow, where we have a SNS -> SQS -> and lambda pick one item at a time from queue and process it. Problem is to have the large no of locations which are processing inside lambda

Comment: Please evaluate 1. AWS batch or 2. AWS Glue

Answer (score 0):

One more option could be to call another lambda function(s), which will do the processing asynchronously.

The API for invoking another lambda is `Invoke` and you will need to provide the `InvokeInput` as the input parameters.